# How am I able to do Forced Alignment on Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to align a transcript I have to a piece of audio, to get the timestamps of when each word was said. However, out of all of the modules I've tried, none of them have seemed to work; I don't know if it's because I'm doing something wrong or something isn't downloading right. Is there an easier way to do this?

I've tried using Aeneas:

```
audio_file = "audio.wav"
text_file = "text.txt"
syncmap_file = "syncmap.json"

config_string = f"task_language=en|os_task_file_format=json"
task = Task(config_string=config_string)
task.text_file_path_absolute = text_file
task.audio_file_path_absolute = audio_file
task.sync_map_file_path_absolute = syncmap_file

ExecuteTask(task).execute()
task.output_sync_map_file()
```

Yet I'd constantly get the error message along the lines of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test.py", line 37, in <module>
    task.audio_file_path_absolute = audio_file
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\venv\Lib\site-packages\aeneas\task.py", line 120, in audio_file_path_absolute
    self._populate_audio_file()
  File "C:\...\venv\Lib\site-packages\aeneas\task.py", line 241, in _populate_audio_file
    self.audio_file.read_properties()
  File "C:\...\venv\Lib\site-packages\aeneas\audiofile.py", line 363, in read_properties
    self.log_exc(u"Unable to call ffprobe executable", None, True, AudioFileProbeError)
  File "C:\...\venv\Lib\site-packages\aeneas\logger.py", line 351, in log_exc
    raise raise_type(raise_message)
aeneas.audiofile.AudioFileProbeError: Unable to call ffprobe executable
```

I've also tried Penn Phonetics Forced Alignment:

```
from p2fa_py3.p2fa import align

audio_path = "dstm.wav"
transcript_path = "text.txt"

output_dir = "syncmap.json"

align.align(audio_path, transcript_path, output_dir)
```

... to another error:

```
'HCopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'HVite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test.py", line 49, in <module>
    align.align(audio_path, transcript_path, output_dir)
  File "C:\...\p2fa_py3\p2fa\align.py", line 451, in align
    _alignments = read_aligned_mlf(output_mlf, sr, float(wave_start))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\p2fa_py3\p2fa\align.py", line 188, in read_aligned_mlf
    f = open(mlffile, 'r')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\p2fa\\aligned.mlf'
```

[Here are the files that I'm using.](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20231127mgDIkQUh) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the problem you're trying to solve, but WRT the first error, you can download ffprobe as a standalone binary, it's part of the ffmpeg suite ... https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

Comment: Please make sure you have followed the [installation instructions](https://pypi.org/project/aeneas/#installation) and have FFmpeg.

Comment: I'm able to import ffmpeg and ffprobe as modules on their own... I've downloaded it, and I've trued changing the config_string to direct to the specific files, but nothing has worked- is their a specific location to put the download? I'm using PyCharm on Windows, which might be part of the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've also tried pip installing aeneas (I believe I'm using a py3 version of aeneas currently), but I get an error along the lines of `cew_func.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol espeak_Synth` (and other unresolved things from espeak). I've installed espeak as well, would I need to put the espeak files in my project file, or something else?

Comment: The general fix for link-time errors is the same everywhere: Compile espeak locally instead of installing binaries someone else compiled; _or_ get your versions to sync up with the versions used by the binaries you installed somewhere else compiled (that might mean installing an older version of espeak, if an older version is what the maintainer used when they compiled the library you installed).

Comment: "FileNotFoundError" generally means what it says. If you think a file exists but you get a FileNotFoundError trying to open it, check the file permissions, check the name for typos, check that the Python interpreter is running in a context where that name is valid (not, for example, in Docker; or compiled with msys or cygwin, or so forth). Checking whether you can use `os.listdir()` on a parent directory (and, if that fails, a parent of _that_ directory, etc) can be a step towards figuring out the exact point in walking the filesystem where things go wrong.

Comment: (and the HCopy and HVite errors are things where you should check your PATH to make sure the directory containing the executables you want to invoke is present within it).